# How can I apply transition to next slide using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a quiz which will consist of a number of slides, while going between the slides using I want to apply a transition similar to [this site](https://theouai.co.uk/pages/hair-consult) where the next card slides in slightly.

I have tried applying the transition on my `.active` classes but this doesn't appear to have any affect.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LMVdwZ)

HTML:

```
      <div class="row main-row align-items-center diagonal-stripe-1">
         <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">

            <div class="card card1 w-50 active">
               <div class="card-body text-center">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Questionnaire</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">This is some example text to show on landing page for questionnaire.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary first-btn">Get Started</a>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card card2 w-50">
               <div class="card-body text-center">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Next Question Goes Here</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">This is some example text to show on landing page for questionnaire.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</a>
               </div>
            </div>

         </div>
      </div>

   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-row {
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  height: 80vh;
}

.diagonal-stripe-1 { background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPScxMCcgaGVpZ2h0PScxMCc+CiAgPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9JzEwJyBoZWlnaHQ9JzEwJyBmaWxsPSd3aGl0ZScvPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9J00tMSwxIGwyLC0yCiAgICAgICAgICAgTTAsMTAgbDEwLC0xMAogICAgICAgICAgIE05LDExIGwyLC0yJyBzdHJva2U9J2JsYWNrJyBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9JzEnLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg=="); background-repeat: repeat; }

/* CARD STYLES */
.card {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.card.active {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: 2s;
  /*transform:translate(0);*/
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".first-btn" ).click(function() {
      console.log( "Handler for .click() called." );
      $(".card1").toggleClass('active');
      $(".card2").toggleClass('active');
   });
});
```

Comment: your css transition declaration is simply invalid. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) for how to declare it

Comment: I've also used `transition: margin-left 2s;` which has no affect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your active card was not showing, I've tried to show your `card2` first and call `setTimeout` to `toggleClass`, and it works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".first-btn" ).on('click', function() {
      $(".card1").toggleClass('active');
      $(".card2").show();
      setTimeout(() => {
        $(".card2").toggleClass('active');
      }, 10)
   });
});
```

```css
.main-row {
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  height: 80vh;
}

.diagonal-stripe-1 { background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPScxMCcgaGVpZ2h0PScxMCc+CiAgPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9JzEwJyBoZWlnaHQ9JzEwJyBmaWxsPSd3aGl0ZScvPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9J00tMSwxIGwyLC0yCiAgICAgICAgICAgTTAsMTAgbDEwLC0xMAogICAgICAgICAgIE05LDExIGwyLC0yJyBzdHJva2U9J2JsYWNrJyBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9JzEnLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg=="); background-repeat: repeat; }

/* CARD STYLES */
.card {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.card.active {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  /*transform:translate(0);*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      
      <div class="row main-row align-items-center diagonal-stripe-1">
         <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">

            <div class="card card1 w-50 active">
               <div class="card-body text-center">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Questionnaire</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">This is some example text to show on landing page for questionnaire.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary first-btn">Get Started</a>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card card2 w-50">
               <div class="card-body text-center">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Next Question Goes Here</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">This is some example text to show on landing page for questionnaire.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</a>
               </div>
            </div>

         </div>
      </div>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong property, you want

```
transition-duration: 2s;
```

But this belongs under .card so it looks more like this:

```
.card {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.card.active {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  /*transform:translate(0);*/
  //more .active css...
}
```

here's some more info
https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_transition-duration.asp

Comment: This doesn't achieve the desired affect, or any change at all. Can you please try to fork the CodePen to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are missing:

```
.card.active {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  -webkit-animation: slideIn 2s forwards;
  -moz-animation: slideIn 2s forwards;
  animation: slideIn 2s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-900px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-900px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-900px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

You could check the following fiddle or check [codepen fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXPxZj):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".first-btn" ).click(function() {
      console.log( "Handler for .click() called." );
      $(".card1").toggleClass('active');
      $(".card2").toggleClass('active');
   });
});
```

```css
.main-row {
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  height: 80vh;
}

.diagonal-stripe-1 { background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPScxMCcgaGVpZ2h0PScxMCc+CiAgPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9JzEwJyBoZWlnaHQ9JzEwJyBmaWxsPSd3aGl0ZScvPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9J00tMSwxIGwyLC0yCiAgICAgICAgICAgTTAsMTAgbDEwLC0xMAogICAgICAgICAgIE05LDExIGwyLC0yJyBzdHJva2U9J2JsYWNrJyBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9JzEnLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg=="); background-repeat: repeat; }

/* CARD STYLES */
.card {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.card.active {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  -webkit-animation: slideIn 2s forwards;
  -moz-animation: slideIn 2s forwards;
  animation: slideIn 2s forwards;
  /*transform:translate(0);*/
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-900px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-900px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-900px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      
      <div class="row main-row align-items-center diagonal-stripe-1">
         <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">

            <div class="card card1 w-50 active">
               <div class="card-body text-center">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Questionnaire</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">This is some example text to show on landing page for questionnaire.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary first-btn">Get Started</a>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card card2 w-50">
               <div class="card-body text-center">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Next Question Goes Here</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">This is some example text to show on landing page for questionnaire.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</a>
               </div>
            </div>

         </div>
      </div>

   </div>
```

***See link for more details regarding CSS [Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) and [Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)***